# How to yield from a generator which takes every item from another generator?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, generator

I am trying to simplify a algorithm in which there are 3 generators such that the main generator couples the other two generator to return the result.

```py
def main():
        try:
           # here is some code for which try is required
            while True:
                for _, element in read_events(): # here is the first generator namely `read_events`
                    yield from factory(element)  # here is the second generator namely `factory`
                # HERE is some more code that requires the generator to exit for it to run
        finally:
            pass
```

Here is my question, how do I simplify it or more precisely get rid of the for loop and make it sleek.

Edit: some clarifications about `try` block and the `while` loop

Comment: well for one you can delete the `try: finally: pass` -- other than that I don't think you can simplify this at all

Comment: well yes, but actually no because I need the main to be an generator as well.

Comment: Surely `main()` is a generator solely because of `yield from`?

Comment: so you are saying I can delete the `try: finally: pass` setup without losing the generator characteristic.

Comment: Ok, then what do *you* think it takes to turn a function into a generator?

Comment: `yield` or `yield from` is what makes a generator, not `try: finally:`

Comment: yes I know it sorry for the stupid comment. I just stripped this code from  a larger chunk that is why its like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `chain.from_iterable` to convert the `for` loop into a generator expression, though I think it's a matter of opinion whether this make the code
more readable or not.

```
from itertools import chain


def main():
    while True:
        yield from chain.from_iterable(factory(e) for _, e in read_events())
```

You can even get rid of the `while` loop by using the 2-argument form of `iter`. I find it a little harder to read, but arguably, everything important is "up front" at the beginning of the expression: yield from the results of applying `factory` to a series of events. Where those events come from is secondary.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

def main():
    yield from (factory(e) for _, e in chain.from_iterable(iter(read_events, None)))
```